# Add editor with using TextButton

Tags: gxt

Is it possible that I can do this?

```
rowEditing.addEditor(catConfig, new TextButton());
```

I would like to have an editor with a textbutton in that way I could display my DualListField since I don't see any tutorials on how a DualListField would work having an addEditor.

Comment: Which version of GXT ?  http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:roweditablegrid

Comment: @wall-e GXT 3.1
I can't view the link you gave